# How does one control the flow of an Akka Stream based on another stream

Tags: akka-stream

Say that I have two sources:

```
val ticks = Source(1 to 10)
val values = Source[Int](Seq(3,4,4,7,8,8,8,8,9).to[collection.immutable.Iterable])
```

I'd like to create a `Graph[...]` processing step in Akka Stream that based on the current value of the `ticks` streams it consumes as much as possible in the values stream. So for instance, when values match I want to return all the elements that match in the second source, otherwise keep ticking resulting in an output like:

```
(1, None)
(2, None)
(3, Some(Seq(3)))
(4, Some(Seq(4, 4)))
(5, None)
(6, None)
(7, Some(Seq(7)))
(8, Some(Seq(8,8,8,8)))
(9, Some(Seq(9)))
(10, None)
```

How would you implement this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd recommend you take a look at the Akka Stream Documentation on this subject: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/stream-graphs.html

According to the site, you can implement a GraphStage like this:

```
final class AccumulateWhileUnchanged[E] extends GraphStage[FlowShape[E, immutable.Seq[E]]] {

val in = Inlet[E]("AccumulateWhileUnchanged.in")
val out = Outlet[immutable.Seq[E]]("AccumulateWhileUnchanged.out")

override def shape = FlowShape(in, out)
}
```

There is also a blog post on this subject: http://blog.kunicki.org/blog/2016/07/20/implementing-a-custom-akka-streams-graph-stage/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you please give specifics?  Your answer simply states that it is possible to write a custom stage, it doesn't provide a stage to solve the given question...